# Multiple delegate or datasource connection on the storyboard

Tags: ios, delegates, storyboard, datasource

How can I link the multiple delegate & datasource to one controller on the storyboard?

**Explaination** :

The "Intake Form Controller" is inherited `UITableViewController` already, so you can see the connection about TableView Delegate & DataSource on the right side of 'connection inspector menu'.

And you can see the PickerView below of the screen, it seems another ViewController but actually it is included in the same Controller on the storyboard. (You can check it on the red rectangle.)

And in the header file of the `IntakeFormController.h`, I declared PickerDelegate & Datasource already,
like this :

```
@interface IntakeForm1ViewController : UITableViewController <UIPickerViewDelegate, UIPickerViewDataSource>
```

What I want to know is how can I see that declared delegate & datasource on the storyboard connection inspector. 
Simply, I want to connect multiple delegate & datasource connection to one Controller.

I know we can do this things on the source code, but I think there's a way to solve this on the StoryBoard.

- Additional Explain.
  In the 'connection inspector menu' on storyboard or Interface Builder, it has a 'Referencing Outlet' field to connect between GUI object and delegate&datasource(declared in .h file) by mouse dragging.
  But if we declare several delegates or datasources on .h file, storyboard or IB shows only ONE delegate point on its own screen.
- So what I want to know is, Is there a way to see that several delegate or datasource on the storyboard or IB's 'Referencing Outlet' menu. Because I don't want to make a delegate from the source code such as 'tableview.delegate = self' things.

Thanks

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can see all the relationships of a view-controller at a time in "connection inspector "by selecting a whole view controller.

**You have to select a certain control on view-controller then you are able to see its corresponding  relations that is delegates,connections or events in "Connection (Relationship) inspector".**

On multiple selection of controls xcode shows you `blank window` in "Connection (Relationship) inspector".

Comment: I understand your saying pretty sure, but I still wish someone could figure out how to do that ;)

Comment: Oh, I'll explain more details on the body. ^^;